# Exception in servicemix while i try to make javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jax-rs, cxf, apache-servicemix

I hope on your help with that question. I use servicemix to work with my jar.

With my dependency

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
```

my xml looks like

```
<bean name="controller" class="first.rest.service.TestService"></bean>

<jaxrs:server id="server" address="http://0.0.0.0:9001/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="controller"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I try to make simple class with 1 method

```
@POST
@Path("/1")
public Response test(@HeaderParam("Content-Length") int size) {

    Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("unknown method").build();
    return response;
}
```

And I get Exception on the line before "return response";

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl not found by javax.ws.rs-api [497]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1024)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl not found by javax.ws.rs-api [497]
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:154)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:121)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.newInstance(Response.java:864)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:592)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:603)
at first.rest.service.TestService.test(TestService.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl not found by javax.ws.rs-api [497]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:111)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:209)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:136)
... 37 more
```

While I was testing my code only with SpringBoot, I haven`t any error, but now, when I try to use it on Servicemix with cxf I get exceptions.

Even if I add any  The exception is generated anyway.

I try my service with Postman. On the server I had javax.annotation-api-1.2 , so ... error happens too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange but the error stopped to appear after I added getter in me controller TestService.class.  It seems that cxf use getter to get some information from class

Comment: Can you been more specific about the solution? What getter have you add to your controller?

Comment: Hi, I can't now look at the code, but I remember, that I had setters and hadn't getters. I add last one to the class, perhaps for every fields in class and exception stoped. I can't tell you which one exactly.